# How to use a global InkToolbar for multiple InkCanvas controls?

Tags: xaml, uwp, windows-10-universal

So I have a `ListView` made up of multiple `InkCanvas` controls (which basically are pages of a document). Now I would like to use a global `InkToolbar` for all of my pages (the InkCanvas controls). However, `InkToolbar` only allows to bind to a single `TargetInkCanvas` object and I am not really sure how I can get around that and design my pages so they all share the same InkToolbar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so I found a workaround. The solution is rather unelegant but it does work. It is possible to handle pointer input in an `InkCanvas` prior to processing. This can be done 
using `CoreInkIndependentInputSource` class as follows:

```
CoreInkIndependentInputSource core = CoreInkIndependentInputSource.Create(inkCanvas.InkPresenter);
core.PointerEntering += PointerEntering;
```

Then in my `PointerEntering` event handler, I can change propagate the signal that the current canvas should be bound to the `InkToolbar` (in my case I had to use `VisualTreeHelper` to propagate the information to the parent ListView).

Answer (score 0):

> How to use a global InkToolbar for multiple InkCanvas controls?

`InkToolbar` only allows to bind to a single `TargetInkCanvas` in xaml code with `x:bind` scheme. If you do want a global `InkToolbar`, please try to set `TargetInkCanvas` in the code behind when you use the specific `InkCanvas`.

```
private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    inkToolbar.TargetInkCanvas = MyInkCanvas;
}
```

Comment: yes that's something I thought of. Does `InkCanvas` has some sort of "pen hovering" event?

Comment: InkCanvas will handle basic input event, so we could not listen pointer entry or point move event.

Comment: But then how I would I know which InkCanvas the toolbar needs to bind to. For example I have two InkCanvas controls, then I would like to use the same InkToolbar for both of them, now I would like that when the user uses the first one the InkToolbar binds to that and when the user uses the other it binds to that.

Comment: Please add the button on the top of inkCanvas, and set `TargetInkCanvas` manually in the button click method

Comment: Thanks but I think you are not understanding my problem. I cannot use a button to switch between the canvas, that's obviously a trivial thing to do. I need it to happen to *automatically*. Suppose you are in a word document, in order to write on different pages would you really want the user to click on a button before switching to a different page? No, obviously that would be a terrible user experience.

Comment: Yep, I know requirement, please try to add the border around the inkcanvas and listen the `PointerEntered` event then set the TargetInkCanvas  in it.

Comment: I found an alternative solution, check out my answer